Issue "Events" > "online payment" > Invalid integer part 100,00. Invalid digit
When trying to pay a event fee via online payment, we get error below when we submit the form:
 Sorry, there was an error processing your payment. Please try again later.Invalid integer part 100,00. Invalid digit , found

After searching the web I came across the following issue:
https://github.com/moneyphp/money/issues/593
Current "locale" setup (/civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1)

Default Language: Nederlands (Nederland)
Inherit CMS Language: No
Default Language for contacts: Use default site language
Default Currency: EUR
Formatting locale: -none-

Alter "Default language"
Altered "locale" setup

Default Language: English (United States)
Inherit CMS Language: No
Default Language for contacts: Use default site language
Default Currency: EUR
Formatting locale: -none-

Submitting the form with the register button brings me to the "Mollie" payment page.
This solution won't work on the long term, because the platform is mostly in Dutch
Trying the Formatting locale:

Default Language: Nederlands (Nederland)
Inherit CMS Language: No
Default Language for contacts: Use default site language
Default Currency: EUR
Formatting locale: English (United States)

Gives me following error:
Sorry, there was an error processing your payment. Please try again later.{"status":422,"title":"Unprocessable Entity","detail":"The amount is required for payments","field":"amount","_links":{"documentation":{"href":"https:\/\/docs.mollie.com\/overview\/handling-errors","type":"text\/html"}}}

Anyone any advice?
Installation

Drupal 10.2.3
CiviCRM 5.75.0
nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor 3.24


Wouter - I think this will fix if for you https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/commit/4d14b3dd115de043962cb4c36f706893cd60972e - if it does let me know and I will tag a release

Hi Eileen
It works!
I did get another error:
 Sorry, there was an error processing your payment. Please try again later.{"status":422,"title":"Unprocessable Entity","detail":"The amount is required for payments","field":"amount","_links":{"documentation":{"href":"https:\/\/docs.mollie.com\/overview\/handling-errors","type":"text\/html"}}}

But this was a problem with German Umlaute characters present in the description. Created a PR: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/pull/270
Thanks for the quick follow-up!

I resolved this issue with the fix provided by Eileen;
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/commit/4d14b3dd115de043962cb4c36f706893cd60972e
Together with the following PR;
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/pull/270
PS: I also have PR 255 applied;
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/pull/255
I had to fix composer compatibility issues to work with D10;
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/issues/259
